# Relations between the commutator of two subsets and set theoretical notions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $X,Y$ are two subsets of some group $G$, then
$$
 [X,Y] := \langle [x,y] : x \in X, y \in Y \rangle
$$
is the commutator subgroup generated by $X$ and $Y$ (where $[x,y] := x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)$. Are there any relations involving commutators 
and set theoretical operations. Well known for example is that if $N,M$ are normal subgroups, then
$$
 [N, M] \le N \cap M.
$$
Also the [Three-Subgroups Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma) is well-known, and that for subgroups $[X,Y]$ is normal in $\langle X, Y \rangle$.

Are there any other, relating intersection, union and so on? I conjecture that if $N, A, B$ be normal subgroups, then $[N, A \times B] = [N, A][N, B]$ (where I mean the internal direct product of groups), one direction follows by $[x,yz] = [x,z][x,y]^z$, for the other direction I have no idea, so this is just a conjecture.

Any way, do you know some relations? In my textbooks I did not find any others then the one mentioned above.

Comment: $[N,A][N,B] \le [N,A \times B]$ is clear!

Comment: Yes, it is, of course ... O_o ... so I found some relation never mentioned in textbooks :)